# CTE not sorting

Tags: sql, sorting, common-table-expression

I am having a problem with sorting in a stored procedure using a CTE. If I don't use the case statement then the sorting works but I need to be able to sort on any one of four columns.

Any help would be most appreciated. Here is the segment of the stored procedure in question....

DECLARE @ValuationIds ValuationIdTableType

```
    ;WITH CTE
    AS
    (
        SELECT V.[Id], Registration, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER
        (
            ORDER BY  
                CASE WHEN @SortCol='Registration' and @Direction='DESC' then Registration END DESC,
                CASE WHEN @SortCol='Registration' and @Direction='ASC' then Registration END ASC
        )) AS seq 
        FROM [Valuation] V WITH (NOLOCK)
          INNER JOIN dbo.Vehicle a ON a.Id = V.VehicleId
          INNER JOIN dbo.Derivative b on b.Id = a.DerivativeId
          INNER JOIN dbo.Model c on c.Id = b.ModelId
          INNER JOIN dbo.ModelRange d on d.Id = c.ModelRangeId
          INNER JOIN dbo.Manufacturer e on e.Id = d.ManufacturerId
          LEFT JOIN dbo.Disposal f ON f.ValuationId = V.Id            
            CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT TOP 1 *
                FROM dbo.SellerAdvanceValuation savCA
                INNER JOIN udf_SplitIDs(@CentreIdList) IdList 
                ON IdList.EntityID = savCA.CentreId 
                WHERE V.Id = savCA.ValuationId
                ORDER BY Id DESC
            ) sav 
        WHERE [Deleted] = 0
          AND f.Id IS NULL
          AND COALESCE(@Registration, [Registration]) = [Registration]
          AND COALESCE(@VehicleStatusId,[VehicleStatusId] ) = [VehicleStatusId] 
          AND COALESCE(@StartDate,sav.RequestDateTime ) <= sav.RequestDateTime 
          AND sav.RequestDateTime <= COALESCE(@EndDate,sav.RequestDateTime ) 
          AND sav.Amount IS NOT NULL
          AND sav.ValuationDateTime IS NOT NULL
          AND sav.ValuationDateTime > @ValuationExpiryDateTime
    )
    INSERT INTO @ValuationIds(ValuationId)
    SELECT a.Id
    FROM CTE a
    WHERE seq BETWEEN @StartIndex AND (@StartIndex + @MaxRows - 1)

    EXEC dbo.Valuation_Get_All @ValuationIds
```

Update:
If I do the following it works but I really do not want to do it this way. I have 4 columns and must do ascending and descending on each.

```
DECLARE @ValuationIds ValuationIdTableType

    ;WITH CTE
    AS
    (
        SELECT V.[Id], Registration, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER
        (
            ORDER BY  Registration DESC
                --CASE WHEN @SortCol='Registration' and @Direction='DESC' then Registration END DESC,
                --CASE WHEN @SortCol='Registration' and @Direction='ASC' then Registration END ASC
        )) AS seq 
        FROM [Valuation] V WITH (NOLOCK)
          INNER JOIN dbo.Vehicle a ON a.Id = V.VehicleId
          INNER JOIN dbo.Derivative b on b.Id = a.DerivativeId
          INNER JOIN dbo.Model c on c.Id = b.ModelId
          INNER JOIN dbo.ModelRange d on d.Id = c.ModelRangeId
          INNER JOIN dbo.Manufacturer e on e.Id = d.ManufacturerId
          LEFT JOIN dbo.Disposal f ON f.ValuationId = V.Id            
            CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT TOP 1 *
                FROM dbo.SellerAdvanceValuation savCA
                INNER JOIN udf_SplitIDs(@CentreIdList) IdList 
                ON IdList.EntityID = savCA.CentreId 
                WHERE V.Id = savCA.ValuationId
                ORDER BY Id DESC
            ) sav 
        WHERE [Deleted] = 0
          AND f.Id IS NULL
          AND COALESCE(@Registration, [Registration]) = [Registration]
          AND COALESCE(@VehicleStatusId,[VehicleStatusId] ) = [VehicleStatusId] 
          AND COALESCE(@StartDate,sav.RequestDateTime ) <= sav.RequestDateTime 
          AND sav.RequestDateTime <= COALESCE(@EndDate,sav.RequestDateTime ) 
          AND sav.Amount IS NOT NULL
          AND sav.ValuationDateTime IS NOT NULL
          AND sav.ValuationDateTime > @ValuationExpiryDateTime
    )
    INSERT INTO @ValuationIds(ValuationId)
    SELECT a.Id
    FROM CTE a
    WHERE seq BETWEEN @StartIndex AND (@StartIndex + @MaxRows - 1)

    EXEC dbo.Valuation_Get_All @ValuationIds
```

Comment: What do you mean "the sorting works"?  The only `order by` is in a `row_number()` statement.  If there is no ordering, then presumably the variables are set incorrectly.

Comment: If I do Order By Registration DESC then it works. When I use the case statement it doesnt

Comment: Gordon, you were right. It was the parameter. Like a muppet I had declared the parameter @Direction as a varchar(3) instead of varchar(4). Oh well, its been a long day. Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO @ValuationIds(ValuationId)
    SELECT a.Id
    FROM CTE a
    WHERE seq BETWEEN @StartIndex AND (@StartIndex + @MaxRows - 1)
    ORDER BY {*ColumnFromInCTE*}

????

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding a CTE, I do not have to put an order by on the Select from CTE part that you mention because I am already sorting it in the CTE itself. The problem is the case statement is simply not working. Its driving me nuts lol

Comment: you aren't sorting on anything. you are creating a field named seq but you aren't using it to sort

Comment: you either add it after the @ValuationExpiryDateTime filter
ORDER BY seq


or where i mentioned previously

Comment: Actually, the code was fine. It was the parameter declaration that was wrong. I mistakenly put a varchar(3) instead of a varchar(4) so when I tried to sort descending it would not work. You do not need to specify the sort when you select the CTE because the sort is being applied within the CTE itself.